# Whats the difference between blt (branch less than ) / slt (set less than) and lw (load word) / sw (store word)?

Tags: assembly, mips

1. Does blt and slt compare two registers the same way?
   When do i use one over the other?
2. As far as i know:

lw (load word) saves a word from memory to register.

sw (store word) saves a word from register to memory.

Does an array (for example 12($s6)) count as a memory? Whats the practical difference of sw and lw? I dont know when to use each.

Comment: blt is a pseudoinstruction. The compiler will probably emit an slt and a beq or bne.

Comment: 12($s6) is not an array, it a memoru address (the result of adding the contents of $s6 with the immediate 12)

Comment: You use sw when you want to store a value (which currently is on a register) in memory. That way you can "free"that register for other purposes

Comment: You use lw when you want to operate with that stored value. You bring it from memory to a register so you can operate with it. Then you possible store the updated value againt, etc

Comment: When you're writing in C or other language that uses `x = array[2];` for assignment, a load is kind of like the difference between assigning a local var = a global, array element, or dereferenced pointer.  A store is like the reverse, with the memory thing on the left hand side of the assignment.  This has nothing to do with branching (blt) or comparing into a boolean 0/1 (slt); don't combine multiple unrelated questions into one SO question.

Comment: Do you have a computer?  If so, you can download MARS 4.5 and try it with some simple code sequences.  MARS is a fully self contained MIPS simulator, and integrated development environment.  (It just requires java.)  These simple tests will answer your questions.  When you do it, be sure to observe how pseudo instructions expand into multiple real MIIPS instructions.  This can be seen after assembling when it shows the machine code.  You can also single step over the machine code instructions to experiment with how they work.

Comment: Additional resoures: godbolt.org can show you what a compiler would do with various C/C++ language constructs -- it has several MIPS compilers to choose from.